# Echo AFC field based on users meta data country setting

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using AFC and I'm able to switch the echoed output based on the shipping and billing information. I'd like to create another function based on the users country setting.

I'm calling the function like this:

```
<?php $sidetext1 = get_field('section_one_sidetext_one' . addLanguage($order), 'options'); ?>
```

My AFC fields are set with a name with a country prefix at the end: _de, _nl and such.

The function:

```
function addLanguageSuffix($order) {
$lang = $order->billing_country;
if (empty($lang)) {
    $lang = $order->shipping_country;
}
if (empty($lang)) {
    return "";
}
$lang = strtolower($lang);
if ($lang == 'nl') {
    return "";
}
switch ($lang) {
    case 'en':
        $lang_code = $lang;
        break;
    case 'be':
        $lang_code = $lang;
        break;
    case 'de':
        $lang_code = $lang;
        break;
    case 'ch': // Zwitserland
        $lang_code = 'de';
        break;
    case 'at': // Oostenrijk
        $lang_code = 'de';
        break;
    default:
        $lang_code = 'en';
        break;
}

return "_" . $lang_code;
}
```

How do I change this function to call from the users country settings instead? I tried something like this, which fetches only the default (EN) when my user is set to DE. Obviously not correct but to give an idea what I want to do.

```
function addLanguage($country) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_locale = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'locale', true);


if ($user_locale == 'nl') {
    return "";
}
switch ($user_locale) {
    case 'en':
        $locale_code = $user_locale;
        break;
    case 'be':
        $local_code = $user_locale;
        break;
    case 'de':
        $local_code = $user_locale;
        break;
    case 'ch': // Zwitserland
        $local_code = 'de';
        break;
    case 'at': // Oostenrijk
        $local_code = 'de';
        break;
    default:
        $local_code = 'en';
        break;
}

return "_" . $local_code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own `get_field()` function to handle this a bit cleaner maybe. If I'm following your question correctly.

Here is a rough idea of what you could do, follow my comments in code...

```
<?php

/**
 * get multilingual acf field by current user locale
 * @param string $selector
 * @param string|int|bool $post_id
 * @param bool $format_value
 * @return mixed
*/
function get_field_ml($selector, $post_id = false, $format_value = true) {

   // global post
   global $post;

   // if post_id is not defined (this can be a string too for options fields) then default to current post id
   $post_id = $post_id === false ? $post->ID : $post_id;
   
   // you should move these two vars to a global scope so they are only called once on page load, but I will place them here for demo purposes
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
   $user_locale = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'locale', true);

   // create a default locale (english) if locale is not set against current user
   $user_locale = $user_locale ? $user_locale : 'en'

   // get the current locale acf field
   $field = get_field($selector . '_' . $user_locale, $post_id, $format_value);
   
   // if current locale acf field does not have data
   if(!$field) {

       // then get the default (no country code) locale acf field instead
       $field = get_field($selector, $post_id, $format_value);

   }

   // return multilingual acf field
   return $field;

}
```

Then you use the below `get_field_ml()` function like this...

```
<?php $sidetext1 = get_field_ml('section_one_sidetext_one','options');
```

...rather than using the standard `get_field()` acf function.

---

Ok here is solution that will probably solve you issue for the current usage as discussed.

```
/**
 * get multilingual acf field by woocommerce order billing country
 * @param string $selector
 * @param string|int|bool $post_id
 * @param bool|object $order
 * @return mixed
 */
function get_field_ml($selector, $post_id = false, $order = false) {

    // global post
    global $post;

    // if post_id is not defined (this can be a string too for options fields) then default to current post id
    $post_id = $post_id === false ? $post->ID : $post_id;

    // set order locale as default
    $order_locale = false;

    // if order billing country is set
    if(isset($order->billing_country)) {

        // override default locale with billing country locale
        $order_locale = strtolower($order->billing_country);

    }

    // create a default locale (english) if locale is not set against current user
    $order_locale = $order_locale ? $order_locale : 'en';
    
   // get the current locale acf field
   $field = get_field($selector . '_' . $order_locale, $post_id);
   
   // if current locale acf field does not have data
   if(!$field) {

       // then get the default (no country code) locale acf field instead
       $field = get_field($selector, $post_id);

   }

   // return multilingual acf field
   return $field;

}
```

Then you use the below `get_field_ml()` function like this...

```
<?php $sidetext1 = get_field_ml('section_one_sidetext_one','options',$order);
```

---

To get the order object in your email footer, add this code below to your `functions.php`...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'email_footer_before', 10, 1 );
function email_footer_before( $email ){
    $GLOBALS['email'] = $email;
}
```

And then in your email footer template add this near the top...

```
global $email;
$order = $email->object;
echo '<pre>' . print_r($order, true) . '</pre>'; exit;
```

You should hopefully now see your order object data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218252/discussion-on-answer-by-joshmoto-echo-afc-field-based-on-users-meta-data-country).